# Parameterized SQL Query error

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameterized

I have an application that builds dynamic parameterized SQL queries. The following query returns an inner exception of "syntax error at or near "="...

I am thinking it is in the way that I am assigning the parameter to the column name but, I'm not sure. Code follows.

```
SELECT TOP 50 77 AS Repository, DocID, LastFileDate, ImageCount,
 LockedUserID,   DocClass, Offline, FileType, OrigFileName, C_CredCardSSN, C_CredCardName,C_CredCardDocType, C_CredCardDocDate, C_CredCardStatus 

FROM D77 

WHERE C_CredCardSSN 

LIKE C_CredCardSSN = @sp1% 

ORDER BY C_CredCardSSN,C_CredCardName
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to everyone. All of these answers helped. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try just

```
WHERE C_CredCardSSN LIKE @sp1
```

or

```
WHERE C_CredCardSSN LIKE @sp1+'%'
```

depending on why you had a "%" there (thanks to Joel Coehoorn's comment for pointing out the "%" I'd missed).

Or (in response to your comment) maybe:

```
WHERE C_CredCardSSN LIKE ''+@sp1
```

Comment: only 1 of 2 problems fixed here

Comment: The problem I get here is that it will now return an error that says I must declare a scalar variable \"@sp1"\.  This was where I started at and had added the "C_CredCardSSN = @sp1" to fix. If it helps, this is all constructed in a string builder and then passed a command text to a SqlCommand object

Answer (score 4):

The LIKE statement should look like this:

```
WHERE C_CredCardSSN LIKE @sp1 + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WHERE C_CredCardSSN like @sp1 + '%'
```

This will only find your C_CredCardSSN if the first few characters are correct. To find anything within that value try it like this

```
WHERE C_CredCardSSN like '%' + @sp1 + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the '%' to the text before adding it as a parameter to the query:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@sp1");
p.value = C_CredCardSSNText + "%";
```